# how to fetch a field in ConsumerRecord

Tags: python, apache-kafka, namedtuple

I wrote a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('dimon_tcpdump',group_id='zhg_group',bootstrap_servers='192.168.100.9:9092')
for msg in consumer:
    print msg
    # process mes here
```

the msg output is like:

```
ConsumerRecord(topic=u'ditopic', partition=0, offset=6280, timestamp=None, timestamp_type=None, key=None, value='myvalue')
```

I know the output is a namedtuple form.

My problem is: how can I get a specific field of the `ConsumerRecord`? 
For example, I want to assign the value string to a variable.

Comment: I'd guess you can call `msg.value` to extract the field `value`?

Comment: >>> msg=r'''ConsumerRecord(topic=u'ditopic', partition=0, offset=6280, timestamp=None, timestamp_type=None, key=None, value='myvalue')'''
>>> msg
"ConsumerRecord(topic=u'ditopic', partition=0, offset=6280, timestamp=None, timestamp_type=None, key=None, value='myvalue')"
>>> msg.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
>>>

Comment: It should be 'msg.value' -- not sure why it does not work for you. See the code example in the README https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python#kafkaconsumer

Answer (score 6):

It might have to do with how your deserializing the data. For example, if you wanted to grab some JSON from the `msg`. You would initialize the `Consumer` with:

`value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8'))`

So your code would look something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
   'dimon_tcpdump',
    group_id='zhg_group',
    value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
    bootstrap_servers='192.168.100.9:9092'
    )
for msg in consumer:
    print msg.value
    # process mes here
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know your `msg` is of type `namedtuple`, you can access its fields simply by attribute lookup, e.g:

```
for msg in consumer:
    value_to_process = msg.value
```

---

In the comment section, it seems that you were re-assigning the output string of `msg` to `msg` by:

```
msg = r'''ConsumerRecord(topic=u'ditopic', partition=0, offset=6280, timestamp=None, timestamp_type=None, key=None, value='myvalue')'''
```

That was why you were getting `AttributeError`: at this point `msg` is overwritten and becomes a `str` object, but `str` does not have `value` attribute.